# File Upload handling in Django rest framework

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, antd

I am trying to add a filefield in my django models but I am not sure how to handle the files coming from React Front-end.

Models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
    short_code = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0,unique=True)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='products/', null=True, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Serializer.py

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = "__all__"
```

When the File is uploaded from Frontend it gives the following error in Network

> {"detail":"Unsupported media type "multipart/form-data
> boundary=967753268136369" in request."}

I have gone through the documentation of DRF and I am sure I need to implement MultiParser in it but I am not sure how.
Also Is there a better way to handle "File Handling"? I am using Ant Design File Upload in the application

Answer (score 4):

Specify the `MultiPartParser` in your generic views or viewsets, then the `media-type` is dynamically set to `multipart/form-data` by the parser, this parses multipart HTML form content, which supports file upload

```
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser

class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser]
    ...
```

Or you could make use of the `FileUploadParser` as described in [DRF Doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser) as follows:

```
class FileUploadView(views.APIView):
    parser_classes = [FileUploadParser]

    def put(self, request, filename, format=None):
        file_obj = request.data['file']
        # ...
        # do some stuff with uploaded file
        # ...
        return Response(status=204)

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^upload/(?P<filename>[^/]+)$', FileUploadView.as_view())
]
```

**Note**: this way, you have to manually set request header `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=upload.jpg`

> The `FileUploadParser` is for usage with native clients that can upload
> the file as a raw data request. **For web-based uploads, or for native
> clients with multipart upload support, you should use the
> `MultiPartParser` instead**

Comment: is it the same url when using a router ?